# I want to activate Google+ on my Google Apps account but I am not given the option

Tags: google-plus, google-apps-for-work

I want to activate Google+ on my Google Apps account. 
When I click on https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/primary-domain-name the page that opens has the following option only; Sites, Docs, Calendar, Email, Google groups for business. It does not have, an "organization and users" tab which would allow me to enable Google+.

What must I do?

Comment: Are you the super admin of this account?

Answer (score 4):

See [this Google help article](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1631746) on how to enable Google+ for your domain.

As a summary, you need to ensure that **Google Talk** & **Picasa Web Albums** are enabled before you can switch on Google+.  Also, if **Other Google Services** is not available you may have to migrate your organization to the new account infrastructure.

I would also suggest reading the article in full as there are some [considerations to take in to account when enabling Google+](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=1689647)

> **To enable Google+**
>
> 1. Log in to your Google Apps administrator control panel.
>
>    The URL is https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/primary-domain-name, where primary-domain-name is the domain name you used to sign up for
>      Google Apps.
> 2. Click **Organization & users**.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. In the pane on the left, choose the organizational unit for which you want to enable Google+.
>
>    You can enable Google+ for only specific users, using organizational
>      units. [Learn more](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=182442)
> 4. Click **Services**.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Ensure that the following services are turned on for the organizational unit:
>
>    - **Google Talk**, which is listed under **Core Google Apps suite**. If **Google Talk** doesn’t appear there, you’ll need to add
>        the service to your organization’s Google Apps account. [Learn
>        more](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=45690)
>    - **Picasa Web Albums**, which is listed under **Other Google services**. If you don’t see the **Other Google Services** section,
>        you’ll need to migrate your organization’s Google Apps account to the
>        new accounts infrastructure. [Learn more](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/topic.py?topic=28917)
> 6. Under **Other Google Services**, turn on **Google+**.
>
>    [image]
>
> Click **Save changes**.
>
> It may take some time before Google+ is available to all users and
>   they are able to sign up for the service.